# Calculating the normal from 3 points

Tags: matlab, vector

I have three points

```
P0=[x0,y0,z0] 
P1=[x1,y1,z1] 
P2=[x2,y2,z2]
```

and I want to calculate the normal out of them. What I did is:

```
normal = cross(P0-P1, P0-P2);
```

and then I wanted to plot the normal so what I did is,

```
c = normal + P0 %end position of normal vector
quiver3(P0(1), P0(2), P0(3), c(1), c(2), c(3));
```

but it didn't work (It looks like there is an angle between the line and the plane. So it is not the normal).

Any suggestions please?

Comment: what do you mean by "did not work"? I suggest you add an example: the values of `P0`, `P1` and `P1` and a screen shot of your `quiever3` output.

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035659/normal-vector-of-three-points

Comment: Full code might help us help you, as well as the content of your workspace. What "didn't work" means btw ? Did you get an error ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"It has an angle so it is not the normal" . There are two problems.

First problem - you misinterpret how the `quiver3` command works. The first three elements are the start of the quiver (the back of the arrow), but the next three are not the endpoint (your `normal + P0`) - they are the *direction*.  So I think you need to change your code to

```
normal = cross(P0-P1, P0-P2);
normal = normal / norm( normal ); % just to make it unit length
figure
quiver3(P0(1), P0(2), P0(3), normal(1), normal(2), normal(3));
axis equal
```

You can confirm a vector is normal to your plane by confirming that the dot product is zero:

```
disp(dot((P0 - P1, normal));
disp(dot((P0 - P2, normal));
```

You would expect the result to be a "number very close to zero" - rounding error will usually prevent things from being exactly zero (consider any value less than 1e-16 smaller than the length of the vectors to be "zero").

Comment: the dotprodut is not zero it is -1.084202172485504e-019

Comment: Good! That's "zero to within rounding error". It is -0.000000000000000000108 . Close enough for almost anything. How do things look when you set the axes to `equal`?